# Solving $x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor -4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor -4=0$$

I plotted a graph for this, and it is pretty easy to find the solution graphically. However, how do I do it numerically?

[image]

graphically the solutions are  2.449 and -1.414

Comment: Those are close to solutions.  Have you typed the equation correctly?  the equation you typed is cubic, not quadratic.

Comment: I think you must have meant $x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor-4=0$ which has the solutions $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt6$

Comment: @saulspatz i am really sorry i meant x^2

Comment: i shall make edits immediately

Comment: can u solve it now??/

Comment: @MeetLalwani You can also solve the quadratic equation in the same way as the method I mentioned. I solved the cubic equation according your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following through on the edited equation : 
$\displaystyle x^2 - \lfloor x\rfloor - 4 = 0$, 
the real challenge is to attack this problem analytically, without Calculus, 
given that the query includes the algebra-precalculus tag. 
This means that such Calculus methods as taking the derivative are barred.

This also means, (since an analytical method is being sought), that it is better
to avoid graphical analysis, if possible.

Since $\displaystyle x^2 - 4 = \lfloor x\rfloor$, which is an integer, you need to find $x$
such that $x^2$ is an integer.

Let $n \in \Bbb{Z}, n \geq 0$ be taken so that $n = x^2.$

You now have to consider two distinct cases:

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~n - 4 \geq 0}.$ 
Since $\lfloor x\rfloor = (n-4) \geq 0$, and $x^2 = n$, you know that 
$\displaystyle \lfloor x\rfloor = 
\left\lfloor ~\left| ~\sqrt{n} ~\right| ~\right\rfloor \geq 0.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle (n-4) = \left\lfloor ~\left|\sqrt{n}\right| ~\right\rfloor.$ 
Therefore, $\displaystyle (n-4) \leq \left| ~\sqrt{n} ~\right| < (n-3).$

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle (n^2 - 8n + 16) \leq n < (n^2 - 6n + 9) \implies $ 
$\displaystyle (n^2 - 9n + 16) \leq 0 < (n^2 - 7n + 9) \implies $

$\displaystyle \left(n - \frac{9}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4} \leq 0 < \left(n - \frac{7}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{13}{4}.$

With $(n-4)$ assumed $\geq 0$ 
note that $[7 - (9/2)]^2 - (17/4) > 0$ and $[5 - (7/2)]^2 - (13/4) < 0$.

Therefore, if there is any solution, when $(n-4) \geq 0$ it will require that 
$7 > n > 5.$

Manually checking $x^2 = n = 6$, with $\lfloor x\rfloor = (n-4) = 2$, you see that
$2 \leq \sqrt{6} < 3.$

Therefore, $n = x^2 = 6 \implies x = |\sqrt{6}|$ is in fact a solution.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~n - 4 < 0}.$ 
Since $\lfloor x\rfloor = (n-4) < 0$, and $x^2 = n$, you know that 
$\displaystyle \lfloor x\rfloor = 
\left\lfloor ~- \left| ~\sqrt{n} ~\right| ~\right\rfloor < 0.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle (n-4) = \left\lfloor ~- \left|\sqrt{n}\right| ~\right\rfloor.$ 
Therefore, $\displaystyle (n-4) \leq - \left| ~\sqrt{n} ~\right| < (n-3) \leq 0 $ [because $(n-4) < 0$].

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle (n^2 - 8n + 16) \geq n > (n^2 - 6n + 9) \implies $ 
$\displaystyle (n^2 - 9n + 16) \geq 0 > (n^2 - 7n + 9) \implies $

$\displaystyle \left(n - \frac{9}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{17}{4} \geq 0 > \left(n - \frac{7}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{13}{4}.$

With $(n-4)$ assumed $< 0$ 
note that $[3 - (9/2)]^2 - (17/4) < 0$ and $[1 - (7/2)]^2 - (13/4) > 0$.

Therefore, if there is any solution, when $(n-4) < 0$ it will require that 
$3 > n > 1.$

Manually checking $x^2 = n = 2$, with $\lfloor x\rfloor = (n-4) = -2$, you see that
$-2 \leq - \sqrt{2} < -1.$

Therefore, $n = x^2 = 2 \implies x = -| \sqrt{2}|$ is in fact a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If $|x|\geq 3$, then $x^2 > x+4 \geq \lfloor x \rfloor +4$, and no solution is possible.  Therefore the only solutions have $\lfloor x \rfloor = -3, -2, -1, 0, 1,$ and $2$.  Let's see if $\lfloor x \rfloor = -3$ works:

$$x^2-(-3)-4 = 0$$

$$x = \pm 1$$

But neither $\lfloor 1 \rfloor$ nor $\lfloor -1 \rfloor$ equals $-3$ so we have no solution here.

Now try $\lfloor x \rfloor =-2$

$$x^2-(-2)-4 = 0$$

$$x = \pm \sqrt{2}$$

We see that $\lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor \neq -2$ so that's not a solution, but $\lfloor -\sqrt{2} \rfloor = -2$ so we have a solution.

Check the other 4 cases similarly and find that $x=\sqrt{6}$ is the other solution.

Comment: +1 (also) to your answer, for elegance.  However, since the OP lives in the algebra-precalculus world, he may have trouble verifying that $x \geq 3 \implies x^2 > x + 4$.  One approach is that $x \geq 3 \implies (x^2 - x) = (x)(x-1) \geq (3)(2).$

Comment: I like your approach as you've used the property that $4$ is small, so $x^2 > x + 4$ is satisfied for a small number of integers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = x^2 - x - 4$, $g(x) = x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor -4$. Then as $\lfloor x \rfloor ≤ x$ for all real $x$, multiplying both sides by $-1$ gives $g(x) = x^2 - (\lfloor x\rfloor + 4) ≥ x^2 - (x + 4) ≥ f(x)$, $x \in \mathbb R$, with $g(x) = f(x)$ when $x$ is an integer.

$f(x) = 0 \implies x = \frac{1 ± \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx -1.56, 2.56$ using the quadratic formula. Let us deal with the two roots separately.

From the above, $f(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis between $x = -2$ and $x = -1$. Since $f(-2) = g(-2) = 2$ (importantly, $2$ is positive) and $g(x) ≥ f(x)$, $g(x)$ also crosses the $x$-axis between $-2$ and $-1$, so $\lfloor x \rfloor = -2$, hence $g(x) = 0 \implies x^2 - (-2) - 4 = 0, x = -\sqrt{2}$.

Similarly, we know $f(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis  between $2$ and $3$. Thus $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$, and $g(x) = 0 \implies x^2 - 2 - 4 = 0, x = \sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown the graph of the quadratic equation in your question.  However, you have the cubic equation.

$$x^3=\lfloor x \rfloor+4$$

Let , $x>0$ then

$$\lfloor x \rfloor ≤x<\lfloor x \rfloor+1$$

$$(\lfloor x \rfloor)^3-4 ≤x^3-4<(\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3-4$$

$$(\lfloor x \rfloor)^3-4 ≤\lfloor x \rfloor<(\lfloor x \rfloor+1)^3-4$$

Let, $\lfloor x \rfloor=m>0,$

$$\begin{cases}(m+1)^3-m-4>0 \\m^3-m-4≤0 \end{cases} $$

$$\implies \begin{cases} m^3+3m^2+2m-3
>0 \\ m^3-m-4≤0\end{cases}$$

$$\implies m=1$$

$$x^3=5 \implies x=\sqrt[3]5.$$

---

I leave the rest of the x <0 case to you.

Comment: how did u solve the last equations

Comment: @MeetLalwani  we need only integer solutions.start $m=1,2,$ (m>0). You can see if $m≥2$ , then $m^3-m-4$ stricly increasing.Isn't it?

Comment: @MeetLalwani Alternative approach to lone student's comment: $m \geq 2 \implies (m^3 - m) = (m)(m^2 - 1) \geq (2)(3) > 4.$

Answer (score 1):

### $$x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor -4=0$$

Let $x = n + \alpha$ where $n \in \Bbb Z$ and $\alpha \in [0,1)$.

\begin{align}
   x^2 - \lfloor x \rfloor - 4 &= 0 \\
   (n + \alpha)^2 - n - 4 &= 0 \\
   (n + \alpha)^2 &= n + 4 \\
   n + \alpha &= \pm \sqrt{n + 4} \\
\end{align}

Note $n \ne 0$.

If $n > 0$, then
\begin{align}
   x = n + \alpha = \sqrt{n + 4}
   &\implies n \le x < n+1 \\
   &\implies n^2 \le n+4 < (n+1)^2
\end{align}
Since $2^2 \le 2+4 < (2+1)^2$, then $n = 2$ and $\color{magenta}{x = \sqrt 6}$.

If $n < 0$, then
\begin{align}
   x = n + \alpha = -\sqrt{n + 4}
   &\implies n \le x < n+1 \le 0 \\
   &\implies n^2 \ge n+4 > (n+1)^2
\end{align}
Since $(-2)^2 \ge -2+4 > (-2+1)^2$, then $n = -2$ and
$\color{magenta}{x = -\sqrt 2}$.

### CHECK

$\sqrt{6}^2-\lfloor \sqrt{6} \rfloor - 4 = 6 - 2 - 4 \overset{\checkmark}{=} 0$

$(-\sqrt{2})^2-\lfloor (-\sqrt{2}) \rfloor - 4 = 2 + 2 - 4 \overset{\checkmark}{=} 0$

Answer (score 1):

Claim:  Either $2\le x < 3$ or $-2 \le x < -1$.

Proof:  If $x \ge 3$ then $x^2 \ge 3x = x + 2x \ge x + 6 > [x]+4$ so $x^2-[x]-4 > 0$.

If $-1 \le x < 2$ then $x^2 < 4; [x] \ge -1$ and so $x^2 < 3 \le [x]+4$ so $x^2-[x]-4 < 0$.

If $x< -2$ then $x^2 > 4; [x]\le -3$ and so $x^2 > 4 > [x]+4$ and $x^2 -[x]-4 > 0$.

...

So $[x] = \pm 2$.

Let $r = x - [x]$ so $0 \le r < 1$.

So we have $x^2 -[x] -4 = (r\pm 2)^2 - (\pm 2) - 4 = 0$.

Now we can just use the quadratic formula.

If $[x] =2$ then $(r +2)^2 - 2-4 =0$ so $r^2 +4r -2 =0$ and $r = \frac {-4 + \sqrt{16+8}}4=-2 \pm \sqrt {6}$.  But as we need $0 \le r < 1$ we must have $r = -2+\sqrt 6$ and $x = 2 +r = \sqrt 6$ (and as it happens $2< \sqrt 6 < 3$).

If $[x]=-2$ then $(r-2)^2 + 2-4=0$ so $r^2 -4r + 2=0$ and $r = \frac {4\pm \sqrt {16-8}}2 = 2\pm\sqrt 2$ but as $0 \le r < 1$ we must have $r =2-\sqrt 2$ and $x = -2 +r = -\sqrt 2$ (and as it happens $1< \sqrt 2 < 2$ so $-2\le \sqrt 2 < 1$.)

So $x = \{\sqrt 6, -\sqrt 2\}$.